# Dropdown Styling

Tags: field-pack

Hello I've been trying to get a dropdown on my channelform the only way it seems to work is if I do this.

{field:education_level}

this outputs fine like this

```
<select name="education_level">
<option value="0">- Please Select -</option>
<option value="10">No Formal Qualifications</option>
<option value="11">GCSE/GNVQ/O levels</option>
</select>
```

But is there anyway to add either an id and class within the select for for my javascript and styling

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quick/easy solution would be to wrap the element with a div, and build your selector using that.

In jQuery, for example, you could use `$('.select-wrapper select')` to select this:

`<div class="select-wrapper">{field:education_level}</div>`

The CSS selector would be similar, of course:

`.select-wrapper select{ border: 1px solid green; }`